# Insert or Delete Objects if does not match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add `base64Images` of a chart images. I am trying to match the prev chart base64image with the new chart.base64Image.

This is inserting the new charts but not removing the old object with the same id.

Please help me on how to remove the old object with the same id in the code below.

```
[
   {
      "id":"abc",
      "base": "sadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsda"
   },
   {
      "id":"bcd",
      "base": "sadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsda"
   },
   {
      "id":"abc",
      "base": "IwantToKeepThisAndDeleteThePreviousObjectWithTheSameId"
   },
]
```

```
setChartImages((prevState) => { return [...prevState.filter(item => 
item?.image !== chart?.toBase64Image()), 
{id: id, image: chart?.toBase64Image()}] })
```

Comment: if you are trying to filter out same id why not use item.id !== chart.id in your callback?

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris Li stated in the comment, you could possibly use `filter` as:

```
setChartImages((prevState) => {
  const filteredState = prevState.filter(item => item.id !== chart.id);
  return [...filteredState, { id: id, base: chart?.toBase64Image() }];
});
```